# iPhone issue with selected option (Chrome, Safari)

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, click, touch

There is an issue on the iPhone both in Chrome and Safari that is not reproduced on Android mobile device and not reproduced on desktop browsers.
The problem is probably connected with touch events.

Once you click on the "button" on the page to make it active by adding some class (among other buttons as options) on the page and THEN CLICK SOMEWHERE ELSE, then that option becomes unchecked ("active" class disappears). That issue found on iPhone only. Other devices keep that button "selected" if touched somewhere else after the button (a href) was "clicked" (selected by adding class "active").

Browsing SO and Internet didn't help with finding a solution for this issue.

Any ideas what's the problem of this behavior?

Comment: Show what code you have.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I think I'm having a similar issue with an option dropdown selector.